# How to delete AVMetadata of AVExportSession

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am making some light video editing in **swift 4**, reading the video with `AVAsset()` and then using the `AVExportSession` to export the result. Everything works fine except one thing: the *resulted* video keeps the metadata of the *original* video.
This metadata includes (for example) the time and location where the video was taken.
I saw that the `AVExportSession` has a `metadata:[AVMetadataItem]` property, but I don't know how to use it. I set it to `nil` and it didn't work, it still keept the old metadata.
I read the [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmetadataitem) about and it says that you don't create instances nor can modify a metadata item, so how can I do? how can I erase that metadata or write new generated metadata to it?
There is a lot of info about reading metadata, but not much on writing it.

Thanks in advance.

**Aditional links**
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetexportsession

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter metadata with `AVMetadataItemFilter.forSharing()`.
From the spec: `Removes user-identifying metadata items, such as location information and leaves only metadata releated to commerce or playback itself.` (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmetadataitemfilter/1387905-forsharing)

Just add it to your export session:

```
let exportSession = AVExportSession() // choose your appropriate init
exportSession.metadataItemFilter = AVMetadataItemFilter.forSharing()
```